# aws s3 put method params by goamz

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, goamz

Earlier I was using **"launchpad.net/goamz/s3"** 
but for my new project I am using **"github.com/goamz/goamz/s3".**
And there is change in put method of bucket now it has one more param "options"

```
region := aws.USEast2
connection := s3.New(AWSAuth, region)
bucket := connection.Bucket("XXXXX") // change this your bucket name
path := "mypath" // this is the target file and location in S3
//Save image to s3
err = bucket.Put(path,user_content,content_type, s3.ACL("public-read"), options)
```

Above is my code. Can you help me what is expected in options and how I can get the value of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options is defined in [s3.go](https://github.com/goamz/goamz/blob/master/s3/s3.go):

```
type Options struct {
    SSE              bool
    Meta             map[string][]string
    ContentEncoding  string
    CacheControl     string
    RedirectLocation string
    ContentMD5       string
    // What else?
    // Content-Disposition string
    //// The following become headers so they are []strings rather than strings... I think
    // x-amz-storage-class []string
}
```

These options are well documented in the [official S3 api docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html).

In the simplest case, you can just pass nothing. eg:
`bucket.Put(path,user_content,content_type, s3.ACL("public-read"), s3.Options{})`

Comment: I have checked s3.go file earlier but was not sure about that I can pass nothing.                                                                                                    "In the simplest case, you can just pass nothing. eg: bucket.Put(path,user_content,content_type, s3.ACL("public-read"), s3.Options{})"